# Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, razor

I am trying to make multithreaded my program but I am always getting the above error. I have read some posts and I saw that MVC 4 is not completely support multhreading . The little part what am I tried to change as multithreaded in controller you can see here :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Status(bool? checkPage)
{
    try
    {
         bool control = checkPage.GetValueOrDefault(false);
            var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dashboardMngr.getComputerInfo());
            var resultDisabled = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dashboardMngr.getStatus(dashboardMngr.getComputerInfo().Result));

            Task.WaitAll(result, resultDisabled);


            ViewData["Info"] = result.Result.Result;
            ViewData["Status"] = resultDisabled.Result.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception Raised in Stat ---> " + e.Message);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959251/async-and-await-in-mvc-4-controller)?

Comment: yes , I have read , but I have async methods and could't implement anythink from the post

Comment: Wow, that's some ingenious use of multi-threading. You start a new thread, releasing the original thread, and then after the first thread is done, you start another thread, releasing the original thread and waiting for the second thread. Where exactly is this "multi-threading" you speak of? There's no point where you'd actually have anything executing in parallel here.

Comment: okey @Luaan , I am ready to learn correct implementation . I am newbie in this topic.

Comment: I don't know about any shortcut, really. Messing around with multi-threading without a good understanding is bound to cause you hard to debug issues over time. At the very least, try reading through this - http://www.albahari.com/threading/. Most things aren't thread-safe by default - there's a good chance the two methods you're trying to run in parallel simply cannot be run in parallel. Unless you designed them specifically for that, they probably will not work. Second, to actually run them in parallel, you first have to call the `Task.Run`s, and only after both are run, `await` them.

Comment: I have edited the code with new tasks